# launching aws elb instace using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-elb

I am new to terraform and aws, all I want to do is launch an **aws ec2 instance with elastic load balancer with terraform**. I get some of the configuration examples from various sites but don't know what is right way to implement those configurations, what should be the folder structure and everything. I had done it using GUI of aws but not getting much help with terraform.

Here the server should be **apache2**.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your TF code and explain why it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: I get the config code at [link](https://www.edureka.co/community/81388/how-to-create-elastic-load-balancer-using-terraform) and a few more options for different sites but dont know how to fit this, basically I want to know how to start this with TF. Can you suggest some site from where I can start with?

Sorry if I can't make it clear what I really want

Comment: If you are new to TF, TF documentation has beginners tutorials. https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/terraform/aws-get-started

Comment: I had done the same, but know I want to add load balancer to it (which includes taget group and security groups how to add) how can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement of creating Elastic Loadbalancer, using terraform. You will need to create the following resources.
If you already have the EC2 instance created and just want to attach them to ELB.

- Create Target Group
- Create ELB
- Assign the Target Group to your ELB
- Register your existing instance to your Target Group

If you don't have any instance created,

- Create Target Group
- Create ELB
- Assign the Target Group to your ELB
- Create Launch Template/Configuration
- Create ASG, assign the ELB to ASG
- The new instance created through ASG will auto-register to the ELB target group.

Terraform Resource example,

**Launch Configuration**

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "Your_Launch_Configuration" {
  name                 = "launch_conf_name"
  instance_type        = "Instance_Type"
  image_id             = "AMI_image_id"
  key_name             = "Key_Name"
  security_groups      = "security_groups_id"
  user_data            = "User Data"
  iam_instance_profile = "Instance IAM Role"
}
```

**Auto Scaling Group**

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "Your_ASG" {
  name                 = "ASG Name"
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.Your_Launch_Configuration.id
  max_size             = "Max size"
  min_size             = "Min Size"
  desired_capacity     = "Desired Capacity"
  vpc_zone_identifier  = "Your Subnet List"
  tags = [{
    "key"                 = "Name"
    "value"               = "ASG Name"
    "propagate_at_launch" = true
  }]
  health_check_grace_period = "300"
  target_group_arns         = "set of your ELB target Group"
}
```

**Load Balancer Target Group**

```
resource "aws_load_balancer_target_group" "Your_target_group" {
  name     = "Target_group_name"
  port     = "80"
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = "Your_vpcid"
  tags = {
    name = "Target_group_name"
  }

  health_check {
    enabled  = true
    interval = 300  # health check interval
    protocol = "HTTP"  
    timeout  = 300  # timeout seconds
    path     = "/" # your health check path
  }
}
```

**Load Balancer**

```
resource "aws_load_balancer" "your_load_balancer" {
  name               = load_balancer_name
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  internal           = true # if not internet facing
  subnets            = ["List of your subnet id"]
  security_groups    = ["List of your security group id"]

  tags = {
    "name" = load_balancer_Target_group_name
  }
}
```

**Load Balancer Listner**

```
resource "aws_load_balancer_listener" "your_load_balancer_Listner" {
  load_balancer_arn = listner_load_balancer_arn   #arn of your load balancer
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "http"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = listner_Target_group_arn  # arn of your target group
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, thats pretty much I was looking for. One more thing is there, which one should be placed in which file and how to link all these,(what should be the folder structure and which file contain what, this is the major concern)

Comment: You can place all in single file, or you can decouple them in separate files for ELB, and another one for ASG/Launch Configuration. All files should be in your root folder of your work/project folder from where you are executing the terraform command, for eg if you are executing your project in c:\workspace, keep all files in c:\workspace. 
Case 1 (two different files)
c:\workspace
-- ASG.tf
-- ELB.tf
Case 2 : (Single file) 
c:\workspace 
-- main.tf (or any filename but has all the above code in single file)

Comment: Pasting in second comment due to character restriction,
Referencing the data is pretty easy, for example we have to specify the launch configuration in ASG, for that just give the reference like,
launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.Your_Launch_Configuration.id

i.e <AWS_service_name>.<user_specified_name>.id/arn/name etc. These attribute list which you can output are on terraform site. you can choose them as per your requierments.